# How to drop specific word from string only when it appears in full

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
1                                               Hello?
2                                             Control.
3                                        that nan far.
4    Just in the last 20 years since your father di...
5    nan your father made all the financial nan nan...
```

I want to remove the substring 'nan' from the text. To do so, I've been using this:

```
df['words_no_nan'] = df['words'].replace(regex=True,to_replace=r'nan',value=r'')
```

This results in this:

```
1                                               Hello?
2                                             Control.
3                                            that far.
4    Just in the last 20 years since your father di...
5                      your father made all the ficial
```

This mostly works, but this removes 'nan' when it is a occurs in larger words. For example, in row 5, the substring 'financial' became 'ficial'. How do I remove 'nan' if and only if it occurs in full, not as a part of a substring (like financial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a word boundary `\b` so it only matches `nan` before or after a boundry.

```
df['word'].str.replace(r'\bnan\b','',regex=True)
```

out:

```
0                                               Hello?
1                                             Control.
2                                           that  far.
3    Just in the last 20 years since your father di...
4              your father made all the financial  ...
```